# Browser force autocomplete

Tags: laravel-blade

I am working with Laravel.

I have a blade file where a user can be created. The problem is, I create a new user so the user doesn't have the same login or password as me but chrome keep auto filling it with the connected user data. Here is my input :

```
<div class="form-group row  {{ $errors->has('email') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}">
            <label class="col-12 col-form-label" for="email">Email</label>
            <div class="col-12">
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" >
                {!! $errors->first('email', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</div>') !!}
                <div class="form-text text-muted" style="font-size: 12px; font-style: italic">Obligatoire pour la convention</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I tried to add `autocomplete="off"`, `autocomplete="new-password"` on the input and on the form but I can't get rid of this autocomplete.

I even tried to add

```
<input id="login" class="form-control" name="login" type="text">
```

To force it into autocompleting this field, but instead it autocomplete another field (firstname ??? with my current login).

I tried to add

```
$("input, select, textarea").attr("autocomplete", "off");
```

But it's not working either.

Comment: Note: In most modern browsers, setting autocomplete to "off" will not prevent a password manager from asking the user if they would like to save username and password information, or from automatically filling in those values in a site's login form. see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete)

Comment: @Raptor I understand but it's really frustrating since it doesn't make sens because I'm not creating an account for myself because I already have one.